# What system of physics should be used for the subset of reality that is much slower than light, in weak gravity fields, around the scale of 1m?

Tags: philosophy-of-physics

Before you say "Newtonian mechanics", the question is: how do physicists know that Newtonian mechanics doesn't operate on broken logic?

And not just with regards to extreme cases (1 nm objects, or objects moving at .99c with respect to the Earth, or within arm's reach of the event horizon of a black hole). How do physicists know that within the realm of ordinary human existence that Newtonian mechanics is logically consistent?

Comment: Newtonian mechanics is logically consistent because it has a set-theoretic model (assuming set theory is consistent, but that is universally assumed anyway). But it would not matter much even if it was not. Bohr's model of the atom was inconsistent (it mixed classical concepts with ad hoc quantum rules), it did not stop it from making correct predictions. The combination of current quantum theory with general relativity is also inconsistent. The purpose of a physical model is not consistency, it is to efficiently make correct predictions. Consistency is nice, but it is not a requirement.

Comment: @Conifold "Newtonian mechanics is logically consistent because it has a set-theoretic model (assuming set theory is consistent)" Thank you. That is exactly the answer I was looking for. Any papers that discuss the set theoretic model of Newtonian mechanics?

Comment: Suppes worked out set-theoretic formulation of Newtonian mechanics back in 1950-s. There is a discussion of it and references in [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/structure-scientific-theories/#TheStrPerSemVie).

Comment: How is this philosophy?

Comment: @Conifold If a theory is inconsistent, it obviously cannot make correct predictions.

Comment: I think it bears mentioning that the entirety of science is *exclusively* concerned with the behavior of the scale of a tiny, tiny subset of medium-size, medium-temperature, medium-speed, medium-density objects: human scientists and our tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Newtonian mechanics is slightly wrong in any domain. For example, even for 1m objects much slower than light, even in the absence of gravity, Newtonian mechanics will give very slightly incorrect values for kinetic energy and momentum. The more correct values would be the relativistic kinetic energy and momentum. The error is so small we can't measure it, but it's there. (Also Newtonian physics gives a substantially wrong answer for blackbody radiation, but we can just exclude that from the domain of interest.)

What we can say is that *for practical purposes*, if we use Newtonian mechanics in the appropriate domain, we will usually get something *close* to the right answer.

We can't even say Newtonian mechanics is always close to the right answer in the 1m scale, slow, no-gravity domain. We could imagine a chaotic system that is highly sensitive to initial conditions, such as a double pendulum. The errors of Newtonian mechanics in modeling this system would initially be very small, but they would compound over a long enough time period until the result is chaotically very different from a more accurate model that includes QM and relativity. Of course, these modeling errors would be dwarfed by measurement errors, but they would in theory become large.

Naturally, QM and general relativity are also very slightly wrong in any domain.

Comment: Cool answer! Although showing that there's a model for the axioms of Newtonian mechanics would suffice to show that it is logically consistent.

Comment: @Fomalhaut It is logically consistent, it just doesn't quite match reality

Comment: It's not 'slight wrongness' that's the issue. Fundamental constants are only known to a given number of decimal places, sure. But the clues to our theories being incomplete are things like dark matter and dark energy, which show that entire dynamics are not explained.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which aspects of reality interest you. If you wish to consider colliding billiard balls, Newton's laws may be appropriate. If you wish to calculate the behaviour of springs within their elastic limit, Hooke's law is your man. If you are interested in figuring out what thickness of cable you need to install, in order to satisfy the wiring regulations, you should apply Ohm's law. And so on.

How do we know these laws are logically consistent? I am not sure how you would establish a test of logical consistency between, say, Ohm's law and Hooke's law. What determines the usefulness of the collection of equations and principles known as classical physics is not the extent to which they are logically consistent but the extent to which they model reality with an acceptable trade-off between accuracy and effort.

Incidentally, your specification for the limited subset of reality you intended to consider might be more specific if you considered time and temperature. At sufficiently low temperatures, for example, it can become more important to take quantum effects into account. More generally, even within the limited subset of reality that you have specified, there are many phenomena which you can explain only by reference to quantum theory.

Comment: You would show that Ohm's Law & Hooke's Law can be derived from the same fundamental theories.

Comment: @CriglCragl thanks but I have several reservations about that suggestion!

Comment: Shared axioms or assumptions can be used to construct the same general results, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency Ohm's Law https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law#Microscopic_origins (ie electron fields) & Hooke's Law from chemical bond strengths https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law#Relaxed_force_constants_(generalized_compliance_constants) (so also electron interactions)

Answer (score 1):

Newton, in his own words, considered action at a distance to be:

> "so great an Absurdity that I believe no Man who has in philosophical
> Matters a competent Faculty of thinking can ever fall into it."
>
> — Isaac Newton, Letters to Bentley, 1692/3

So in a very real sense Newton's Theory of Gravity is not, was not, and has never been considered logically consistent. This results from the still upheld physics principle of no [action at a distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_at_a_distance), which was a crucial part of defining physicalist-matetialism and the scientific paradigm.

It was only with General Relativity that we understood:

> "matter tells spacetime how to curve, and curved spacetime tells
> matter how to move"
>
> -John Archibald Wheeler

The idea you need is that of an [Effective Field Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_field_theory). This is the way we make tractable simplified theories for particular situations, by using the relevant degrees of freedom, and ignoring or averaging out the full complexity of the real world and of more complete theories. Ignoring the dynamics of very high gravity fields, very small things, and relative velocities close to the speed of light, is exactly an example. Ignoring relatively rare inelastic scattering of particles off atomic nuclei lets you ignore basically the whole impact of the Weak Nuclear Force and Electroweak Theory just keeping it for fission and fusion related situations, as another example.

'Logically consistent' is not the criteria for science, which focuses on *experimentally consistent*. If the world behaves in ways many think illogical, like the Michaelson-Morley Experiment failing to find the luminiferous aether, scientists just have to take that on board and adjust their models. You say 'how do they know?' and the short answer is, experiment.

The long answer is, experiments distinguish between theories, but how theory generation happens in cases regarding phenomena far beyond our direct experience, is actually quite a mystery. We can be sure that it's not algorithmic - theories do not follow from basic science like geometry from it's axioms. You can compare it to how the descriptions in a piece of literature cannot be predicted from the nature of the alphabet. Theory-making involves gigantic leaps in accurate descriptions, over the equivalent of trying every letter order and seeing if it matches.

We have heuristics, like predictive power, Occams razor, etc, but in practice these are guidelines not logical requirements, and within specific subdisciplines you will find nearly all such guidelines are sometimes suspended from consideration or even ignored.

Comment: Action at a dstance is neither an absurdity nor a brokenness. A world where forces act with zero latency is fine.

Comment: @Fomalhaut: Newton & Einstein disagreed. But you do you.

Comment: How did Newton and Einstein come to view action at a distance as an absurdity? Why did they come to reject zero latency as an unthinkable thought?

Comment: @Fomalhaut: As I said in my answer it's about the transition to a physicalist-materialist paradigm, from for instance a cosmic-mind cosmology (Plato), or a teleonomic or intentions-based paradigm (Aristotle). I see the primary advantage of this shift as being locality, you only have to deal with the influences having measurable impacts at a given place to work out outcomes. Action-at-a-distance is a well established principle & well evidenced paradigm, if you want to take issue with it I recommend reading up. Idealists & othets don't accept it, but it really helps in doing science.

Comment: That's very good. I did not know that >0 latency is presumed because it guarantees locality. But video game developers often craft universes with both >0 latency and locality. So that might be evidence that while >0 latency is sufficient for locality, it may not be necessary.